# Warning: overriding remoting type user loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, strongloop

I'm working on a strongloop API project. When i start the server with "node ." command, i'm getting some warnings like:
Warning: overriding remoting type user.

Can some one tell me what can cause this warning? Please ...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think its because you tried to override an existing `loopback` model. `loopback` is shipped with its own `User` model and you tried to create a new `User` model which will override `loopback`'s `User` model.